# How to allow an image to be resized by zooming in, while setting its initial size using vh/vw units?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have too much code in different components (using vue.js btw) to figure out an efficient way to post it all, but I believe I can describe the situation clearly:

I have a div containing an image.  The div is sized so that its width is based on viewport width (vw) units.  This is so that I can fit the div to fit the width of the browser and not overflow in the x direction **initially**.

However, I want the user to be able to zoom in on the image, thus causing it to overflow in the x direction.  My problem is that I cannot find a way to allow my image/the div it is a part of to be zoomed in or out, because the width was set to be equal to vw units.

I need to keep the width formatting in vw units because when someone resizes the browser, I want to the picture (initially at 100% zoom) to resize to fit the browser by width.

Is there a way to set an image's width based off of vw, but still allow it to be zoomed in upon?

Comment: How are you implementing the zoom - does the user click on a button you have provided for example, and is it just that div that you want to zoom?

Comment: As the image is within a div which has width 100vw could you let the img have width 100% initially? I may be misunderstanding what you want to do when the window resizes  - is there some reason the img could not keep its zoom whatever that is in % terms at the time in terms of the width of the div (which is always 100vw so will resize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep the containing div at 100vw all the time you can start the img off at 100% width and then zoom just the img. If the window is resized the containing div will resize to still fill the width of the window and the zoom of the img will resize to match.

Here's a simple example which allows zooming either by clicking buttons or by using e.g. a mouse wheel

```html
<head>
<style>
#mydiv {
  width : 100vw;
}
#mydiv div.buttons {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
}
</style>
<script>
function zoom() {//this function called from onwheel event on the image
  event.preventDefault();  
  if (event.deltaY<0) { zoomIn(); }
  else { zoomOut(); }
}

//this is the original code which scales on Zoom in and Zoom out buttons
function zoomIn() {
  var w=Number(myimg.style.width.replace('%',''));
  if ((w <= (maxsteps*step + 100))) {
    myimg.style.width=(w+step) + '%';
  }
}
function zoomOut() {
  var w=Number(myimg.style.width.replace('%',''));
  if (w > step) {
    myimg.style.width=(w-step) + '%';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="zoomIn();">Zoom in</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut();">Zoom out</button>
  </div>
    <img id="myimg" src="https://rgspaces.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/junction-arch-and-tricycle-and-box-1024x768.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
</div>
<script>
const myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
const step = 10;//or however many vw (=% of div width) you want the div to zoom on a click
const maxsteps = 10;//the maximum number of zoom steps you allow the user to take

myimg.addEventListener("wheel", zoom);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Is there a way to cause the scrollwheel on the mouse when doing ctrl+scrollwheel to zoom the image in and out as well, maybe using some js?  If that isn't possible with vue, I will definitely adopt this example as it gets the job done!

Comment: Yes, zooming on the wheel as well as (or instead of) clicking on buttons is possible. I have edited the code snippet in my answer to do both. It only needed an onwheel= in the img and deciding whether to zoom in or out depending on whether there was wheel movement forward or back.

Comment: As some browsers (e.g. Firefox, IE) do not support onwheel I have changed the code to addEventListener('wheel'... on the img.as the common desktop browsers seem to support that.